# clearRect function not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, rect

I have some code that should be clearing a 50px wide gap in a rect(). But for some reason it isn't working. I've tried several different ways, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**My Code**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var rectWidth = 50;
var rectHeight = 50;
var rectRad = 25;
var x = (canvas.width / 2) - rectRad;
var y = canvas.height - 100;
var dx = 4;
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;
var leftPressed = false;
var rightPressed = false;

function rect() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, y, rectWidth, rectHeight);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function bar() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.clearRect(50, 0, 100, ch);
  ctx.rect(0, (ch / 2) - rectRad, cw, 50);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF9900";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}



function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  rect();
  bar();

  if (leftPressed == true && x + dx > 0) {
    x -= dx;
  }

  if (rightPressed == true && x + dx < cw - rectWidth) {
    x += dx;
  }
}
setInterval(draw, 10);

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
  }

  if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
  }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 37) {
    leftPressed = false;
  }

  if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

Comment: Where are you attempting to clear a 50x50 rectangle? And maybe the problem is you're clearing the rectangle before you draw it?

Comment: 50px from the left of the bar. And its not that cause I tried changing the order but it didn't work.

Comment: I notice you are not calling stroke at all. Javascript canvas is a little confusing it doesn't actually draw anything until you call the stroke method. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/stroke

Comment: But I called fill() Thomas Devries. I thought the only difference is stroke() is hollow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to clear the area in the rectangle before you draw the rectangle. You have to call clearRect after you call fill.

Also, you're drawing it in the wrong spot slightly.

```
function bar() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(0, (ch / 2) - rectRad, cw, 50);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF9900";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.clearRect(50, (ch/2) - 25, 50, 50); // this line
}
```

Comment: Could have been done with `function bar () { ctx.fillStyle = "#F90";ctx.fillRect(0, (ch / 2) - rectRad, cw, 50); ctx.clearRect(50, (ch/2) - 25, 50, 50); }` As you have it the `ctx.closePath` is redundant and does nothing and why use `beginPath` and `fill` when it's only one rectangle.

Comment: I decided not to change OP's code too much because that wasn't the question. I'm sure OP had a reason he wanted to do it this way as well. If he's planning to add to his path with other shapes or rectangles or lines, then this is a pretty versatile way to do it.